# How to enable self-built qemu as a backend in virtmanager/virsh?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, kvm, virsh

I have built a qemu with some modifications, and it can run correctly with cmd like `./qemu-system-x86-64 ....`, but I failed to integrate it into virt-manger, even if I added it to `PATH` ahead of default system lib.

Comment: Strangely maybe, but this looks more like a Superuser question or Unix & Linux. Altho you build your own version of qemu, its not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option in XML file, you can edit it to enable your own qemu.

```xml
<devices>
    <emulator>/path/to/your/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
.........
```